# What is the purpose of having the concept of fasting in Islam?

Tags: ibadah, sawm

In some other religions, believers have fast as a part of their ibadat (worship). In the case of Islam, why do Muslims have fast? What is the purpose of fast from the perspective of Islam? Is it for learning to restrain yourself, or does it have any other aim?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Islam, ultimately, any and all forms of worship are because God told us to worship him this way. Sometimes He told us more, showed us the extra benefits, but that's just detail.

Now that being said, there are many benefits to fasting, and I'll list some in no particular order:

1. Earning a great reward from God: There's a narration(Hadeeth)
   from Prophet Muhammad that promises forgiveness of all sins a person
   has committed if they fast Ramadan with sincerity. Optional fasts
   bring you further away from Hell a distance of 70 years.
2. Self-restraint: It teaches you to control yourself, rather than let
   your desires control you.

   Surat Al-Baqarah [2:183](http://quran.com/2/183)

   > O you who have believed, decreed upon you is fasting as it was decreed
   >   upon those before you that you may become righteous -
3. Emphasizing sincerity: Most, if not
   all, other acts of worship have outwards signs(praying, Hajj, etc.)
   But fasting is internal and only you and God know whether you are
   fasting or not.
4. Appreciating what you have: Speaking from
   personal experience, you don't know the value of that morning cup of
   coffee, or that snack in the middle of the day, until you can't have
   it for a month. Hopefully you learn to appreciate it and appreciate
   the plight of those who have to do without.
5. Community bonding:
   There's great emphasis in Ramadan on praying at the masjid, breaking
   fast with the community, and being with each other. It brings the
   community closer together and fosters better bonds.
6. Health benefits: Fasting has many documented health benefits as well.

Answer (score 4):

Other than its spiritual aspects such as God desires and expects His followers to fast, fasting Affects our physical, mental, emotional aspects:

> Fasting will:
>
> - rest the digestive system
> - allow for cleansing and detoxification of the body
> - create a break in eating patterns, while shining a spotlight on them
> - promote greater mental clarity
> - cleanse and heal "stuck" emotional patterns
> - lead to a feeling of physical lightness, increasing energy level
> - promote an inner stillness, enhancing spiritual connection

As to its spiritual aspects, it helps us to maintain a close relationship with God. It helps us to think about ourselves and our life more focused and gives you greater freedom, flexibility, and energy to get done the things that are important to you. It's a short while of difference that we experience every year. A faster would not commit a crime and there's a weird feelings that makes you think of yourself as a good person.

The thing about fasting is, We all need variety and we need time to think about our lives among our busy moments. Fasting gives us the opportunity and it really feels good at the end when you've done what you must have.

Imam Ali (peace be upon him) mentions in his Nahj al-Balaghah about fasting that fasting shows that all people are equal. Reach people understands poor people's condition better and they'll be encouraged to help people from lower economic status.

The prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said:

> The stomach is home to all pain and fasting is the highest remedy.

It doesn't end here, there's already a branch of study on fasting and the philosophical reasons behind it.

Comment: [Intermittent fasting from dawn to sunset for 30 consecutive days](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1874391920300130) is associated with anticancer proteomic signature and upregulates key regulatory proteins of glucose and lipid metabolism, circadian clock, DNA repair, cytoskeleton remodeling, immune system and cognitive function in healthy subjects